# How to extract functions call graph from a visual basic file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, reverse-engineering, legacy-code

I'm currently facing a large piece of legacy code which I have to understand and rewrite to make it more maintainable.

Is there a tool that would show let me explore easily the graph of the function calls in the file ?

Any text output like

```
Method1
    Method2
    Method3

Method2
    Method3
```

Or graphical like

[image: Graph]

could help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Call_Tracking.html) allows your to inspect incoming or outgoing calls to a method.

I don't know of a way to do this in visual studio without a plugin.

Also, [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) might be an option for you as well. I've never used it, but it looks like it can do what you're requesting.

Comment: Here are explanations about how to generate a call graph with NDepend http://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph#Call

Comment: is resharper only for C sharp?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio's Generate sequence diagram?

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/11/20/visual-studio-2010-generating-sequence-diagrams-on-the-fly.aspx

Maybe that is only in Ultimate edition. But you can download trial of it from Microsoft Servers.